# How to get a Java timer to restart on keypress?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to make a tetris game in java and I have a pretty good idea of how to make the game work, i'm just stuck at figuring out how to have the blocks fall every x milliseconds. This is my first attempt ever at a game in Java.

I came across the Timer class quite early and began trying to figure it out, but then started thinking about how the keybindings would affect it because I want the timer to reset before moving the block down again.

Think of it this way...
Block drops, .5sec wait, block drops, .5sec wait, block drops, .25sec wait becuase user hits the down arrow, .5sec wait, block drops... etc

I currently have no code written as i'm just trying to get all my logic stright first.

Current plan: (Pseudo code)

```
while(game is not over)
{
  if(game is not paused)
   {
       getNextBlock();
       while(current block hasn't hit the bottom)
       {
           // x amount of time paused (time will decrease as levels increase)
           dropBlock();
       }
       //check for finished lines and award points/levels
   }    
}
```

What should I look into to be able to deal with the keypress? Or is there perhaps an easier approach to this than using a timer?

EDIT: I'm using Swing and was looking at the Swing Timer. The game is going to be run on a computer (not phone).

Comment: Swing? AWT? Android? What GUI library? What Timer? Swing Timer? java.util.Timer? Other? You're missing some critical information here.

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: There are approximately 2^32 Tetris clones freely available on the 'Net, and many of those include source code.  One of the rules of thumb in software development goes something like "don't reinvent the wheel," so I'd suggest that you find yourself some sample code, take a look at a few examples and see how those authors approached the issue.  You'll probably learn learn quite a bit about threading in games (a non-trivial matter), sprites, animation, collision detection, etc.

Comment: There is no need to restart the timer. The keyPress has nothing to do with the timer. The Timer should fire every .5 seconds and the block should drop whether the user users a keyPress or not. You code should not have while logic. If you pause the game you pause the Timer. The Timer will continue to fire until the block hits the bottom. The idea of using a Timer is that you don't need while loops.